# how to save different file to different location while moving from sftp to local directory using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

```
   @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser("foo");
        factory.setPassword("foo");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setTestSession(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("foo");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }
```

using this(Spring integration) code i am able to move a file from SFTP to local directory.but i want to move all similar file to one folder, that is all pdf to one folder and all xml file to another folder. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is doing the reverse (sending to SFTP).

Use outbound gateways to list (LS) and get each file and put it in a particular directory.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: first time i am using spring integration, can you explain how can i connect with different SFTP  server dynamically ? after researching i found that we can use delegating sessionfactory for that, can you give a sample code how to use that in my code ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments to another answer; it doesn't help others find answers to questions; ask a new question instead.

Comment: It's some time ago, but are you sure, Gary, that this code is doing the reverse? Or was it edited by the asker after you wrote this? I also use this code to get files from a SFTP server into a local directory.

Comment: Yes. The question was edited later. Click the edit link. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62213714/revisions